# What does it mean when no data is returned for valid dimension combinations for historical dates in Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am fetching performance data through BatchGet in the [Google Analytics Core V4 API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet).

With a combination of dimensions

- I get data: When fetching data for dates X > 2018-02-01
- I **don't** get data: When fetching data for dates X < 2018-01-01

Dimensions used:

```
[
  "ga:date",
  "ga:source",
  "ga:medium",
  "ga:campaign",
  "ga:country",
  "ga:countryIsoCode"
]
```

Metrics requested: `ga:sessions`

I have tried to download data for date `2017-10-01` which results in no data.

Using the following dimension sets return data:

```
[
  "ga:date",
  "ga:source",
  "ga:medium",
  "ga:campaign",
]
```

or

```
[
  "ga:date",
  "ga:country",
  "ga:countryIsoCode"
]
```

I expect to get data for the union of the dimension sets which works, but instead it returns no data for the date.

Why is there no data returned with the union of dimensions?

---

Update 2019-04-10:

It seems the issue might be related to the [data retention period](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en).
[image]

Comment: It seems in this case it was related to data retention. However the question remains why the union doesn't return data but the separate requests do. I will add info into OT

Answer (score 0):

You are probably coming up against the facts that

a) an individual GA data row doesn't get populated with every dimension and every measure, only the ones relevant to the particular happening that row is tracking, and

b) GA doesn't return default values for the missing dimensions and measures, just refuses to return the row at all if you ask for a missing dimension or measure.

You'll need to pull the data selectively to a staging post (e.g. a Google Sheet) where you can stick it back together intelligently, setting the right default values. It's a complete pain.

Comment: Not sure how one would be able to stitch the data back together though, perhaps if there was country code in the UTM Campaign or UTM Source.

Comment: I'd probably use the GA cookie (which I have as a user scope custom dimension) and the timestamp (both of which should be present on everything, I would think) to produce a timeline for each of the different types of activity required, then merge them. Depends on the data volumes you have and the reporting use case, obviously. (And no doubt someone with more experience than me could identify a better way to do the join!)